# Apache Ignite cluster node goes offline

Tags: ignite

I have set up an Ignite database cluster by installing two nodes within the same network, with persistence enabled. We have also created a baseline topology consisting of two nodes, but they suddenly disconnect and operate as separate clusters after three months, resulting in data inconsistency. The only information available from the default log [INFO] file is that both nodes claimed the other node went offline. We are new to Ignite database and will sincerely appreciate your help regarding the following questions:

1. What are the possible causes of the issue? (we didn't do anything to the server or the network)
2. How can we adjust the log configuration so that we may obtain more information if something similar happens again? (No connectivity related error message from the default logger)
3. How can we config our cluster to be CP rather than AP? (cap theory)